# Labels not aligned on top left side above text inputs

Tags: html, css, forms

I've been trying to get the labels to be on the left side above the text input, but all I've managed to do is make it towards the center instead. What am I doing wrong? Sorry if the way I'm labelling things seem odd, I'm still very new to HTML and CSS.

[The output that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9U2G.png)

[The output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGHcs.png)

HTML

```
<div class="account-form">
      <form action="/account-sign-up">
        <div>
          <label for="first">First Name</label>
          <input
            id="first"
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. Wan"
            name="first"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="last">Last Name</label>
          <input
            id="last"
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. Aiman"
            name="last"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="e.g. wanaiman@gmail.com"
            name="email"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Must be 9-20 characters"
            name="password"
            minlength="9"
            maxlength="20"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />

        <div id="account-extra">
          Already have an account?
          <a href="sign-in.html" id="account-link">Sign In</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.account-form {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: "Epilogue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f0f3ff;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

input:focus {
  cursor: text;
  color: #303030;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #303030;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Epilogue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f3ff;
}

#account-extra {
  font-family: "Epilogue", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#account-extra a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Add text-align:left in label css

Comment: Try adding these properties in `.account-form{text-align: left; margin: auto; width: 550px;}`

Comment: @ShashankGb This worked for me, thank you! Although I am not able to accept your answer as it is a comment. Would you mind posting it again as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Parent div width to same as your `<input>` width so that you can use `margin:auto` to center a div. Finally you can use `text-align: left` as shown here

```
.account-form{
  text-align: left; 
  margin: auto; 
  width: 550px;
}
```

Note: By default it takes `text-align: left`. I just mentioned because you used `text-align: center`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this piece of code for labels

```
label {
  color: black;
  text-align:left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: "Epilogue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```